# Error in /blog redirection - ubuntu default WP installation

Tags: redirect, htaccess, blog

I have installed WP from the Ubuntu repositories (18.04) and the domain I got was something like `http://snf-XXXXX.vm.okeanos.grnet.gr/blog` (notice the blog at the end).

After some tries to perform a new domain redirect (e.g. `www.example.com` to redirect to `http://www.example.com/blog` I think I did something wrong and broke the `/blog`, meaning that `http://www.example.com/blog` redirects to `http://snf-XXXXX.vm.okeanos.grnet.gr` showing the Apache index.php. Nevertheless `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/index.html` works just fine.

I checked the browser logs and the `/blog` page raised a 301 error, thus it was redirected to root.

My htaccess is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

, which I think it is the default for the Ubuntu installation.

Also in wp-admin/ general options, both URLs are set to `http://www.example.com/blog`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was the Chrome cache... Steps to solve if anyone else stumbles on this: https://www.ryadel.com/en/clear-google-chrome-redirect-cache-for-single-url-page-howto/